# QWidgets getting "squashed" when added dynamically to a QGridLayout

Tags: python, qt, qgridlayout

I am trying to add controls (the number determined in response to user input) to a basic form created with Qt Creator. Unfortunately the GridLayout is not expanding so anything beyond 4 iterations of a 'for' loop all the widgets are getting squashed up. Any ideas as to where to look for a solution would be much appreciated. Thanks in anticipation...

```
import sys 
from CoordinatesUI import Ui_Coordinates
from BuildChord import Ui_BuildChord
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore


class Main(QtGui.QMainWindow):
   def __init__(self):
    self.mvtNum  = None
    self.blockNum = None
    self.progNum = None
    self.chordNum = None
    self.numOfPitches = None


    QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
    self.ui = Ui_Coordinates()
    self.ui1 = Ui_BuildChord()
    self.ui.setupUi(self)

    self.setUpsignals()

def commitCoords(self):
    self.mvtNum = self.ui.txtMvt.text()
    self.blockNum = self.ui.txtBlock.text()
    self.progNum = self.ui.txtProg.text()
    self.chordNum = self.ui.txtChord.text()
    print self.mvtNum, self.blockNum, self.progNum, self.chordNum
    self.ui1 = Ui_BuildChord()
    self.ui1.setupUi(self)
    self.setUpSignals2()
    window.show()

def genPitches(self):
    self.numOfPitches = int(self.ui1.txtNumOfPitches.text())
    sui = self.ui1.gridLayout
    BtnC = QtGui.QPushButton()
    self.showMaximized()
    for i in range(3, self.numOfPitches + 3):
            leP = QtGui.QLineEdit()
            leR = QtGui.QLineEdit()
            leC = QtGui.QCheckBox()
            leP.setObjectName("p" + str(i - 3))
            leR.setObjectName("r" + str(i - 3))
            leC.setObjectName("c" + str(i - 3))
            sui.addWidget(leP,i,3)
            sui.addWidget(leR,i,5)
            sui.addWidget(leC,i,6, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

    BtnC.setText("Commit")
    sui.gridLayout.addWidget(BtnC, self.numOfPitches + 4, 7)

    print "Create clicked", self.numOfPitches

def setUpsignals(self): 
    self.ui.btnCommit.clicked.connect(self.commitCoords)

def setUpSignals2(self): 
    self.ui1.btnCreate.clicked.connect(self.genPitches)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Main()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Here is the QT generated code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'BuildC.ui'
#
# Created: Sun May  3 22:31:44 2015
#      by: PyQt4 UI code generator 4.11.3
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
_fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
def _fromUtf8(s):
    return s

 try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
    return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
    except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
    return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

 class Ui_BuildChord(object):
 def setupUi(self, mainWindow):
    mainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("mainWindow"))
    mainWindow.resize(439, 381)
    self.centralWidget = QtGui.QWidget(mainWindow)
    self.centralWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralWidget"))
    self.gridLayoutWidget = QtGui.QWidget(self.centralWidget)
    self.gridLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(-10, 40, 432, 176))
    self.gridLayoutWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gridLayoutWidget"))
    self.gridLayout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self.gridLayoutWidget)
    self.gridLayout.setMargin(0)
    self.gridLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("gridLayout"))
    self.label = QtGui.QLabel(self.gridLayoutWidget)
    self.label.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label"))
    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 1, 2, 1, 1)
    spacerItem = QtGui.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum,            QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
    self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem, 4, 2, 1, 1)
    self.label_2 = QtGui.QLabel(self.gridLayoutWidget)
    self.label_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_2"))
    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_2, 2, 3, 1, 1)
    spacerItem1 = QtGui.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding,     QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
    self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem1, 1, 4, 1, 1)
    self.label_3 = QtGui.QLabel(self.gridLayoutWidget)
    self.label_3.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_3"))
    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_3, 2, 5, 1, 1)
    spacerItem2 = QtGui.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
    self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem2, 2, 0, 1, 1)
    spacerItem3 = QtGui.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
    self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem3, 1, 0, 1, 1)
    self.label_4 = QtGui.QLabel(self.gridLayoutWidget)
    self.label_4.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("label_4"))
    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_4, 2, 6, 1, 1)
    self.txtNumOfPitches = QtGui.QLineEdit(self.gridLayoutWidget)
    self.txtNumOfPitches.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("txtNumOfPitches"))
    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.txtNumOfPitches, 1, 3, 1, 1)
    self.btnCreate = QtGui.QPushButton(self.gridLayoutWidget)
    self.btnCreate.setDefault(False)
    self.btnCreate.setFlat(False)
    self.btnCreate.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("btnCreate"))
    self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.btnCreate, 1, 5, 1, 1)
    spacerItem4 = QtGui.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
    self.gridLayout.addItem(spacerItem4, 2, 1, 1, 1)
    mainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
    self.menuBar = QtGui.QMenuBar(mainWindow)
    self.menuBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 439, 22))
    self.menuBar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menuBar"))
    mainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menuBar)
    self.mainToolBar = QtGui.QToolBar(mainWindow)
    self.mainToolBar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("mainToolBar"))
    mainWindow.addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.TopToolBarArea, self.mainToolBar)
    self.statusBar = QtGui.QStatusBar(mainWindow)
    self.statusBar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusBar"))
    mainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusBar)

    self.retranslateUi(mainWindow)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(mainWindow)

def retranslateUi(self, mainWindow):
    mainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("mainWindow", "Harmonic Engine", None))
    self.label.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "Enter Number of Pitches:", None))
    self.label_2.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "Pitch Class:", None))
    self.label_3.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "Registration:", None))
    self.label_4.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "Sustain:", None))
    self.btnCreate.setText(_translate("mainWindow", "Create", None))


if __name__ == "__main__":
import sys
app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
mainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
ui = Ui_BuildChord()
ui.setupUi(mainWindow)
mainWindow.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Try setContentsMargins on the widget that you are adding

Comment: Call updateGeometry() on the containg widget

Comment: Unfortunately QLineEdit has no attribute 'setContentsMargins'

Comment: Yes it does, QWidget has a setContentsMargins attribute and QLineEdit inherits from QWidget. I usually set the contentsMargins on the layouts. However, I'm not sure the contents margins have anything to do with it. Perhaps setting the QSizePolicy of the added widgets may help.

Comment: Furthermore, I am unable to run your program. I get an ImportError and also your indentation is a mess. I'd would help us if you make a minimal program (preferably in one file) that still shows the problem, and that we just can copy-paste-execute without having to make any modifications ourselves. I think this will get you a lot more help. Perhaps make it from scratch without using the QtDesigner, at that may give you the insight to solve the issue yourself.

Comment: Is what you are asking for putting the layout into a QScrollArea?